Sendto works on localhost only
I have been trying to fix this but I think I need your help. I am a newbie and I can't seem to find the issue.
The code works when both the source and destination are set to localhost. But when I use real IP addresses other than localhost for both source and destination, it fails. sendto() returns -1.
I don't know how to make `sendto() spit out more details about the error, or what's causing it to return -1.
I'm running Linux, BTW.
Here is the code:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX_PACKET_SIZE 4096

u_int32_t src_addr, dst_addr;
u_int16_t src_port, dst_port;


unsigned short csum (unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
{
    unsigned long sum;
    for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
        sum += *buf++;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    return (unsigned short)(~sum);
}

void setup_ip_header(struct iphdr *iph)
{
    iph->saddr = src_addr;                          // SOURCE IP ADDRESS 
    iph->daddr = dst_addr;                          // TARGET IP ADDRESS

    iph->ihl = 5;
    iph->version = 4;
    iph->tos = 0;
    iph->tot_len = htons(sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr));
    iph->id = htonl(54321); /*setup any arbitrary number for id */
    iph->frag_off = 0;
    iph->ttl = MAXTTL;
    iph->protocol = 6; /* upper layer protocol, TCP*/
    iph->check = 0;

}

void setup_tcp_header(struct tcphdr *tcph)
{
    tcph->source = htons(src_port);                 // SOURCE PORT
    tcph->dest = htons(dst_port);                   // TARGET PORT

    tcph->seq = random();
    tcph->ack_seq = 0;
    tcph->res2 = 0;
    tcph->doff = 5;
    tcph->syn = 1;
    tcph->window = htonl(65535);
    tcph->check = 0;
    tcph->urg_ptr = 0;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    struct sockaddr_in sin;                                         

    const char *src_addr_str = "192.168.1.50";
    src_addr = inet_addr(src_addr_str);
    src_port = 777;

    const char *dst_addr_str = "192.168.1.51";
    dst_addr = inet_addr(dst_addr_str);
    dst_port = 888;

    char datagram[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
    struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)datagram;
    struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *)((u_int8_t *)iph + (5 * sizeof(u_int32_t)));
   
    char new_ip[sizeof "255.255.255.255"];


    int src_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);       

    if(src_socket < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open raw socket.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /* a IP_HDRINCL call, to make sure that the kernel knows
    *     the header is included in the data, and doesn't insert
    *     its own header into the packet before our data
    */
    int tmp = 1;
    const int *val = &tmp;
    if(setsockopt(src_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof (tmp)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: setsockopt() - Cannot set HDRINCL!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


    // SETUP DETAILS ABOUT THE TARGET MACHINE
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = dst_addr;
    sin.sin_port = htons(dst_port);

    // Clear the data
    memset(datagram, 0, MAX_PACKET_SIZE);

    // Set appropriate fields in headers
    setup_ip_header(iph);
    setup_tcp_header(tcph);

    iph->check = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->tot_len >> 1);


    for(;;){

        int ret = sendto(src_socket, datagram, iph->tot_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));

        if(ret == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "sendto() error!!!.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Flooding %s at %u...\n", dst_addr_str , dst_port);
        }

       
        sleep(1);

    }


    return 0;
}

I also noticed that the sizeof(sin) returns only 16, not sure if this is normal. Is that normal?
How can I make the compiler spit out more info about an error when it encounters one?

When it returns -1, read errno to get an indication of what went wrong. Usually format that with something like strerror.

Is there a reason you use raw sockets and construct your own datagrams to send, instead of using the plain standard TCP functionality?

@JerryCoffin I tried errno as below but it does not show anything:  char errBuffer[256]; strerror_r(errno, errbuffer, 256); std:cout << "Error: " << errbuffer << std:endl;

Change fprintf(stderr, "sendto() error!!!.\n"); to fprintf(stderr, "sendto() error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); When you get a sendto error, what is the exact output? Please [edit] your question to tell us (copy-paste the output).

On a couple of other notes, there are some things in the code you show that are... odd. Like sizeof "255.255.255.255" as array size instead of a macro. Or const int *val = &tmp; instead of using &tmp directly in the setsockopt call. Or using fprintf in a C++ program. In fact there's no C++ specific code at all in the shown code, it's all plain C. And using the obsolete random function, and using it for the TCP sequence number. Use of global variables instead of function arguments. Small inconsistencies that just makes it feel strange.

@Someprogrammerdude This is the output:  sendto() error: Message too long

Rather than using fprintf() with strerror() manually, you can use perror() instead, which handles the printing of errno to stderr for you, eg: perror("sendto() error");

In this comment you said:

This is the output: sendto() error: Message too long

You are setting iph->tot_len to the result of htons() and then passing that value as-is to sendto() as the data size. On a little-endian system, you will end up passing a very large number as the data size. In your case, 40 (0x0028) converts to 10240 (0x2800), which causes Undefined Behavior when sendto() tries to send more data than you gave it.
The iph->tot_len field does need to be in network byte order, but the value you give to sendto() needs to be in host byte order, so you will have to convert the iph->tot_len value back with ntohs():
sendto(..., ntohs(iph->tot_len), ...);

Better would be to store the size in a separate variable and then convert it only for the iphdr, eg:
u_short len = sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
...
iph->tot_len = htons(len);
...
sendto(..., len, ...);


I will give this a try when I come back later. I will update you once I am able to give it a try. I don:t understand though why it works when I user "127.0.0.1" (localhost) for both the src_addr and dst_addr

@Xmaki "[Undefined behavior] is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural."

Thank you so much Remy. Hat's off to you. I had to read your comment 3x and had to pull out my scientific calculator literally. You nailed the issue ! You just made me understand why HTONS and such need to be used for tcp. Thank you so much ! Now I can sleep. :p
